# Cropping Circular region of interest around a point in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]

I have an image and I want to crop the circular region of interest around a point. I did following in MATLAB:

```
  vessel=imread('vessel.jpg');
  imshow( vessel)
  t = 0:pi/20:2*pi;
  xc=230; % point around which I want to extract/crop image
  yc=79;
  r=20;   %Radium of circular region of interest
  xcc = r*cos(t)+xc;
   ycc =  r*sin(t)+yc;
   roimaskcc = poly2mask(double(xcc),double(ycc), size(vessel,1),size(vessel,2));
   pr_gccc = find(roimaskcc);
   roimean_cc= mean(vessel(pr_gccc));
  figure, imshow(roimaskcc)
```

roimaskcc is correct but when I do the following it gives in nX1 matrix but not the region of interest under mask:

```
  vessel_undermask=vessel(roimaskcc==1);
```

Can anybody pls. help to extract the circular region of interest around point of interest (xc, yc).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I got it. I did something like that:

```
           vesseltry=vessel;
          vesseltry(~roimaskcc)=0;
```

vesseltry is now my new image with circular region of interest...

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is extract everything from `vessel` that's outside the mask. Since there's no such thing as circular matrices, Matlab's solution is to output a *vector* of all values inside the mask.

While that is technically correct, that vector can be pretty hard to work with. An alternative solution is to leave the data matrix square, and set everything outside the mask to `NaN`:

```
% make a copy      
vessel_undermask = vessel;

% NaN everything outside the mask (in R, G and B layers)  
vessel_undermask(repmat(~roimaskcc,[1,1,3])) = NaN;

imshow(vessel_undermask)
```

This should give you a matrix that's somewhat simpler to work with.

Note that

```
vessel_undermask(~isnan(vessel_undermask)) ==  vessel(roimaskcc)
```