# How to do circular crop using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I usually use `imcrop` to crop rectanguler image but i wat to create circular crop. How to do it?

I know there is another quetion about this, here the link:

1. [MATLAB: how do I crop out a circle from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651778/matlab-how-do-i-crop-out-a-circle-from-an-image)

   ```
   [xx,yy] = ndgrid((1:imageSize(1))-ci(1),(1:imageSize(2))-ci(2));
   mask = (xx.^2 + yy.^2)<ci(3)^2;
   ```

   and the result of `imshow(mask)` is rectangle with white background
2. [Cropping Circular region of interest around a point in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015287/cropping-circular-region-of-interest-around-a-point-in-matlab)

   error in `roimaskcc`
3. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/242489

   ```
   [xx,yy]=ndgrid(1:size(X,1), 1:size(X,2));
   CroppingMask= ( (xx-Xcenter).^2+(yy-Ycenter).^2<=Radius^2 );
   X=X.*CroppingMask;
   ```

   The result of `imshow(CroppingMask)` is a rectangle with black background with small white circular at the center of the rectangle. When I run line 3 it shows an error.

Please help me, step by step because I'm a beginner.

Here is my image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5plqzqgyb1ej6gh/patricia.jpg. It resolution is 480x640.

Comment: The first circular mask question you referenced gives me a nice little circle on a 256x256 image for `ci = [100 100 20]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution (1) works perfectly well. Here is a complete working example using your image.

```
I = imread('patricia.jpg');
imageSize = size(I);
ci = [250, 300, 100];     % center and radius of circle ([c_row, c_col, r])
[xx,yy] = ndgrid((1:imageSize(1))-ci(1),(1:imageSize(2))-ci(2));
mask = uint8((xx.^2 + yy.^2)<ci(3)^2);
croppedImage = uint8(zeros(size(I)));
croppedImage(:,:,1) = I(:,:,1).*mask;
croppedImage(:,:,2) = I(:,:,2).*mask;
croppedImage(:,:,3) = I(:,:,3).*mask;
imshow(croppedImage);
```

It produces the following image.

[image: croppedImage]

I hope this clarifies things. There is probably a better way of re-assembling the cropped image, but this was what I could come up with off the top of my head.

Comment: Thx for your reply but i get this error,,
Error using  .* 
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

Comment: SOLVED - i use this http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html

Thx sir, it was very helpful..

Comment: I'm sorry. I am using GNU Octave (a free MATBLAB clone), that's why the code worked for me but you got the "Error using .* ...". I'm glad you found a solution. I will update my code. I'm not sure what you mean by clearing the black area? Matlab works with matrices and `imshow` shows all values of a matrix. The black area is simply lots of zeros, which when rendered show up as black pixels in the plot. What you **can** do is save the image as a PNG and specify the black area as transparent (see for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16134889/2956886)). Maybe that is what you want?

Comment: i guess Matlab can clear black area. Thx it was very helpfull,,
Sorry for annoying your time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option for non-interactive cropping:

```
R=20; % radius in pixels
x=10;y=10; %Location of upper-right corner of your cropping mask

Mask = fspecial('disk',R)~=0;
[u v i]=size(Mask);

Cropped= imcrop(I,[x y u v]).*Mask;
```

Comment: I think `x+u` and `y+v` should be `u` and `v` here

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect the final output to look? By definition within MATLAB you cannot have a "circular" image as such - just a regular image which where all the points outside the circle are set to some background value.  It is possible, however, to save images out with a transparent background using `imwrite` and either `gif` or `png` formats.

Here's an example using imroi methods (requires Image Processing Toolbox)

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
h = imshow(I);

% define circular roi by square bounding box
x = 10;
y = 10; 
d1 = 100;
d2 = 100; 
e = imellipse(gca, [x y d1 d2]);

% roi can be interactively moved/adjusted
% do not close figure window before createMask is called

%%% these lines are only needed if you move or resize the roi
   pos = getPosition(e);
   x = pos(1);
   y = pos(2);
   d1 = pos(3);
   d2 = pos(4);
%%%

BW = createMask(e,h);
% here assuming your image is uint8
BW = uint8(BW);

I2 = I.*BW; % everything outside circle to black
I2 = I2(x:(x+d1-1),y:(y+d2-1)); % close crop to circle
imwrite('out.png',I2,'Transparency',0);
```

In this case using `'Transparency',0` sets all the black (0) pixels to transparent.  If there are actual black pixels within your area of interest it will also make those transparent.  If this is likely to be an issue, you could crop `BW` to the same size as `I2` and set 'Alpha' instead of `Transparency` (see the `imwrite` documentation for details).

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your problem is to use imcrop to crop a square and use the following code to overlay a circle:

```
function imout = overlay_circle(im)
u = size(im);
mx = ceil(u(2)/2);
my = ceil(u(1)/2);
if (length(u)==3),
    for x=1:u(2),
        for y=1:u(1),
            if (x-mx)^2 + (y-my)^2 > mx^2,
                im(y,x,1) = 0;
                im(y,x,2) = 0;
                im(y,x,3) = 0;
            end
        end
    end
else,
    for x=1:u(2),
        for y=1:u(1),
            if (x-mx)^2 + (y-my)^2 > mx^2,
                im(y,x) = 0;
            end
        end
    end
end
imout = im;
```

Comment: thx for your response,
i create im variable,,
im = imread('patricia.jpg');

but when i use above code it show error

Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context.

Comment: you'll probably need to define the function in a file named overlay_circle.m

Answer (score -1):

```
I = imread('patricia.jpg');
imageSize = size(I);
ci = [250, 300, 100];     % center and radius of circle ([c_row, c_col, r])
[xx,yy] = ndgrid((1:imageSize(1))-ci(1),(1:imageSize(2))-ci(2));
mask = uint8((xx.^2 + yy.^2)<ci(3)^2);
croppedImage = uint8(zeros(size(I)));
croppedImage(:,:,1) = I(:,:,1).*mask;
imshow(croppedImage);
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? Why is your answer better than/different from the other answers?