# Why do my MatLab complain 'undefined function'?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I basically want to do a circular mask for my picture by using the codes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992097/how-to-do-circular-crop-using-matlab). But I get complain like `Undefined function or variable 'imageSize'.` I don't understand why. I have MatLab 2017b with Image Processing Toolbox. Could somebody help me?

Here is my code:

```
ci = [1810, 2550, 1085]; % center and radius of circle ([c_row, c_col, r])
    [xx,yy] = ndgrid((1:imageSize(1))-ci(1),(1:imageSize(2))-ci(2));
    mask = uint8((xx.^2 + yy.^2)<ci(3)^2);
    croppedImage = uint8(zeros(size(b))); % b is my original image
    croppedImage(:,:,1) = b(:,:,1).*mask;
    croppedImage(:,:,2) = b(:,:,2).*mask;
    croppedImage(:,:,3) = b(:,:,3).*mask;
    imshow(croppedImage);
```

Comment: You should define imageSize and all other variables. For example, `imageSize = [10 20];`

Comment: @dhanushka Ah Thank you! Now I realize I mistakenly delete that imageSize line! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you ever define `imageSize` as a variable anywhere?  I would guess that you didn't so Matlab doesn't know what to make of it and thus the error:

> Undefined function or **variable** 'imageSize'

Perhaps define it as the size of your image.

```
>> imageSize = size(b);
```

Comment: Yeah I mistakenly delete that line. Now I solve it and thanks for pointing out!